# Why Jakarta.Servlet-api 6.0.0 is showing License Cast issue

Tags: jakarta-migration

I am using this library in my project
  `<dependency> <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId> <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId> <version>6.0.0</version> <scope>provided</scope> </dependency>`
but when we are scanning for cast issue then its showing license issue

can anyone pls tell which version or what solution  can be which does not show license cast issue?I am using jdk 11 and springboot version 2.6.14[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXjlY.png)
I have added screenshot of cast issue for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is related to your CastHighlight configuration (https://doc.casthighlight.com/feature-focus-component-license-compatibility/) and perhaps not having setup to cover this dual licence combination as low risk:

Licenses: EPL 2.0 + **GPL2 w/CPE**

(https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api/6.0.0/overview)

The earlier pre-jakarta javax version also had a dual licence, which is probably covered in your configuration as lower risk:

Licenses: CDDL + **GPLv2 with classpath exception**

(https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/4.0.1)